# Ember reloading belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a belongsTo relationship defined in the model, e.g.

```
gallery: DS.belongsTo('store-gallery', { async: true }),
```

Later on, I'll create a new object and assign it to the relationship if it is null:

```
let galleryObject = this.get('store').createRecord('store-gallery', {});
this.set('gallery', galleryObject);
console.log('Created', galleryObject, await this.get('gallery'));
```

The problem is that the `this.get('gallery')` call returns `NULL` due to Ember reloading the relationship.

How do I set the relationship (preferrably without having to convert it to non-async) without it immediately overwriting it?

Answer (score 1):

I did not give what you asked a try and to be honest I am a little bit surprised that this works the way you explained. I would not have expected `ember-data` to reload the relationship; because you are not forcing a `reload` on the relation within the code block you provided.

Aside from what I have just explained; you can always get the current value of the relationship as follows; where `this` is the owner of the relationship as in your example:

`this.belongsTo('gallery').value()`

This will provide you to reach the current value of the relationship even if it is async in a sync way. So you do not even need to have the `await` there. See the official [API documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Model/methods/belongsTo?anchor=belongsTo) to see what I mean. Hope this helps.